# problems in web scrapting with python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrape a page and below is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = ('https://bama.ir/car/all-brands/all-models/all-trims?hasprice=true&sort=1&page1')

html_content = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content,'html.parser')
print(url)

names_car = []
prices = []
works = []

for name_car in soup.findAll('h2',{'itemprop':'name'}):
   names_car.append(name_car.text.replace('\n',' ').replace('\r',' ').strip())

for price in soup.findAll('p',{'class':'cost'}):
   prices.append(price.text.replace('\n',' ').replace('\r',' ').strip())

for work in soup.findAll('p',{'class': 'price milage-text-mobile visible-xs price-milage-mobile'}):
   works.append(work.text.replace('\n',' ').replace('\r',' ').strip())



for i in range(0,29):
   print({'name':names_car[i],'price':prices[i],'works':works[i]})
```

The problems are:

1. When I take the name cars and price and work it's hard to read
2. This code is for just one page. How can I get all pages 
   and other problems (when you run code you can understand).

Comment: that's depends of the language you have set for your local system.

Comment: use https://pypi.org/project/PyArabic/

Comment: If you want all pages, why do you have just `&page1`?